# How to Use SignalA in AndroidStudio

Tags: git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and But I have some experience in android(A Little experience). I am asked to use the Signalr in a project and after reading a lot I know what is it but how to use it in android studio I do not found help. I read the Read me File shared on github but its not helping me .

Then I have came to know that in android studio we can use the SignalA but same problem. The code here [github](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA) , I have downloaded this and I have include the project after extracting it from rar file. But now the problem is how to start and run it ? where to start my own project? I do not know What I am missing . there is no helping material over the internet. So tell me How can I use the Signalr/Signala in my project and How to get started?

when ever i open that project it gives me the following error:

> Can't start Git: git.exe

Comment: You don't explain what the precise problem.

Comment: But now the problem is how to start and run it ? where to start my own project? I do not know What I am missing . there is no helping material over the internet. So tell me How can I use the Signalr/Signala in my project and How to get started?

Comment: Simple How to use the SignalA ? any tutorial or code snippet.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a tutorial website.

Comment: I know it already @shkschneider

Comment: Oh. Could you post some code then? Because "where to start my own project" seems a lot like asking for a tutorial on this website... Plus you don't make it easy for us to help you understand what the mysterious "same problem" is...

Comment: Actually I downloaded the project SignalA from github . And under that project there are many multilevel projects , So in its initial stage after importing the "Run" symbol is disable.

Comment: And as the Signala/Signalr is a very new thing to me., So I wanted to see the full code with example so that I can make my own project.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio uses `Gradle` to build the project.So you have to configure the Gradle build script correctly before you run the project.

You can read [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) to learn `Gradle` first. The Section [Multi project setup](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-project-setup) is telling you how to start a multi-project setup.

Comment: when ever i open that project it gives me the following error
Can't start Git: git.exe

Comment: It has occurred after making some changes in build.gradle file .  but my main purpose of posting this question was to get some starting help with signala . How mean how to get started with the signala